# Shared preferences salvando inteiro errado

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Tô salvando o código de usuário(um inteiro) nas shared preferences:

```
      String a = Integer.toString(pUsuario.getCodigo());

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor_Codigo = oCodigo.edit();
    editor_Codigo.putString(pContext.getString(R.string.codigo_usuario), a);
    editor_Codigo.apply();
```

Pra recuperar eu uso:

```
   SharedPreferences oCodigo = pContext.getSharedPreferences(pContext.getString(R.string.codigo_usuario), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String a = String.valueOf(oCodigo.getString(pContext.getString(R.string.codigo_usuario), "0"));
    return Integer.parseInt(a);
```

Mas não importa o código que salve, na hora de retornar sempre retorna o código "2"

Comment: Porquê converter o inteiro em `String` e utilizar `putString` quando pode utilizar diretamente `putInt` ? Depois da linha `String a = Integer.toString(pUsuario.getCodigo());` esse `a` tem que valor ?

Comment: porque estou salvando nas strings ~> `pContext.getString(R.string.codigo_usuario` ao usar o putint dá um erro.
 O "a" tem o valor certo do codigo, tipo 109. Só na hora de recuperar que retorna 2

Comment: Isso será por outro motivo. O primeiro parametro do `putString`, assim como do `putInt` é o nome que vai ficar associado ao valor que está a ser guardado. E regra geral você quer um nome determinístico e não baseado na língua pois esse é um nome que não será visível ao usuário e apenas para uso interno da aplicação.

Comment: fiz o putint, ele grava o valor. Aí quando vou dar o getint dá a excessão: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

Comment: E como está a fazer esse `getInt` ? eu começava por simplificar todos esses puts e gets para usarem nomes diretos com algo como `editor_Codigo.putInt("codigo_usuario",pUsuario.getCodigo());`. A tradução das strings ai só esta a complicar e não é necessária para o efeito.

Comment: usando o nome das strings direto deu certo. Mas então qual o propósito de fazer um `getstring`?

Comment: O proposito de `pContext.getString(R.string.codigo_usuario)` é obter textos para mostrar ao usuário, que possam ser traduzidos com base na lingua que o dispositivo detetou. O texto que vai para o `putInt` é o nome **interno** associado ao valor que você guarda. Esse não deve ser traduzido pois é um nome interno, logo não faz sentido traduzir.

Comment: Pra mim não faz sentido ter esse método e não ser possível pegar o valor associado a essa string, mas tudo bem, resolveu o problema.

Comment: O problema é que usar isso torna a `String` onde vai buscar o conteúdo potencialmente dinâmica, podendo mudar com a utilização. Significa que agora você faz `putInt("usuario", 10);` e daqui a pouco, quando for buscar, está a fazer `getInt("user", 10)` porque apanhou a nova `String` com base na tradução aplicada. Pode sempre pegar no código original que tinha e fazer `Log` das várias `Strings` que está a apanhar em `pContext.getString(R.string.codigo_usuario)` para conseguir isolar o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
private String KEY_CODIGO = "KEY_CODIGO";

SharedPreferences.Editor editor_Codigo = oCodigo.edit();
editor_Codigo.putString(KEY_CODIGO , pUsuario.getCodigo());
editor_Codigo.commit();
```

Na busca do valor:

```
SharedPreferences oCodigo = pContext.getSharedPreferences("file.preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String codigo = oCodigo.getString(KEY_CODIGO , ""));
return Integer.parseInt(codigo);
```

Aconselho utilizar o *SharedPreferences* em uma classe pra somente fazer essa busca pra facilitar problemas futuros como esse. Eu utilizo no meu app essa classe, fique livre pra copiar, editar, distribuir etc.

```
public class Preferences {

    private Context mContext;

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private String FILE_NAME = "app.Preferences";
    private int MODE = Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

    private String KEY_LOGGEDUSERID = "KEY_LOGGEDUSERID";
    private String KEY_LOGGEDUSERNAME = "KEY_LOGGEDUSERNAME";
    private String KEY_EMERGENCYID = "KEY_EMERGENCYID";
    private String KEY_EMERGENCYNAME = "KEY_EMERGENCYNAME";
    private String KEY_TIMEDELAY = "KEY_TIMEDELAY";

    public Preferences(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, MODE);
        editor = preferences.edit();
    }

    public void setLoggedUserId(String id) {
        editor.putString(KEY_LOGGEDUSERID, id);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getLoggedUserId() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_LOGGEDUSERID, "");
    }

    public void setLoggedUserName(String name) {
        editor.putString(KEY_LOGGEDUSERNAME, name);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getLoggedUserName() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_LOGGEDUSERNAME, "");
    }

    public void setEmergencyUserId(String id) {
        editor.putString(KEY_EMERGENCYID, id);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getEmergencyUserId() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_EMERGENCYID, "");
    }

    public void setTimeDelay(String time) {
        editor.putString(KEY_TIMEDELAY, time);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getTimeDelay() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_TIMEDELAY, "");
    }


    public void setEmergencyUserName(String name) {
        editor.putString(KEY_EMERGENCYNAME, name);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getEmergencyUserName() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_EMERGENCYNAME, "");
    }

}
```

Quando eu preciso recuperar o valor apenas uso:

```
Preferences preferences = new Preferences(this);
String loggedUserId = preferences.getLoggedUserId();
```